# How can I remove punctuation but remain acronyms and hyphenated words in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove punctuations of a text in Java. I know there is a pattern to match all punctuations, i.e. \p{Punct}, but that will remove all punctuations. However, I want to remain acronyms and hyphenated words. For example, remain "m.i.t." or "state-of-the-art", "9.4", "11:00", "p.m.", "976-4275" while I am removing punctuations.

I tried \p{Punct}, but it will remove all punctuations.

```java
String text = "There's a string from M.I.T., written by Jason at 11:00 p.m. 976-4275, 9.5, another word is state-of-the-art.";

text.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");

System.out.println(text);
```

The result will be:

```java
"There s a string from MIT written by Jason at 1100 pm 9764275 95 another word is stateoftheart"
```

But what I want is:

```java
"There s a string from M.I.T. written by Jason at 11:00 p.m. 976-4275 9.5 another word is state-of-the-art"
```

Comment: Remember to do `text = text.replaceAll(regex)`! Since Java Strings are immutable, text will not change if you don't assign the result from `replaceAll`.

Comment: Why is the apostrophe replaced by a space with `"There's"`, which became `"There s"`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add the code `&&[^.]` after the `\\p{Punct}`, it will help you to replace all punctuation except the full stop punctuation.

Solution:

```
text.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^.]]", "");
```